# Database is not stored on Android Phone Device

Tags: android, database, cordova, storage, android-sqlite

I am developping an Android Application (Android 4.1.2) with PhoneGap (Cordova 2.2.0).

I am using [Cordova Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) :

I am following different examples found on internet in order to learn how to manipulate a database on Android like this one [Create Android App with SQLite using Phonegap + Jquery mobile](http://luthfihariz.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/android-sqlite-phonegap-jquerymobile/)

In fact, my problem is that I am not sure if the database is physically created on the real device (I am testing on real device running with Android 2.3):

- I checked in the folder /data/ with file Explorer but it was collapsed and I couldn't expand it (May be some System Administrator issues?! If it is the case, how can I become root?)
- I checked directly on the phone, but I didn't even find the Application directory! (Is it normal? )

=> So I am not sure if the Database was created, or not.

Why I am thinking that the database is not created?

In fact, everytime I launch my app the table is empty although I populated it earlier.

I have also this error in LogCat:

```
sqlite returned error code = 14 msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

I did some researches and i found that this code in onCreate function could solve the problem:

```
    WebSettings settings = super.appView.getSettings(); 
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true); 
    String databasePath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", 
                           Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath(); 
    settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
```

But it didn't solve it.

My code is simple, I read a QR-Code and I save it in a Table with the location:

```
var scanCode = function() {
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result) {  
        alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
                + ". Format: " + result.format
                + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        getPosition(result.text);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Scan failed: " + error);
    });
}

function getPosition(data) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position, result){
                launchDB();
                latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                db.transaction(function(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql("insert into DEMO(code,updated, latitude, longitude) values(?,?,?,?)",[data, new Date(),latitude, longitude]);
                },errorCB,successInsert);
            }, positionError);
}

function launchDB() {
    console.log("launchDB()");
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(setupDB, errorCB);
}

function setupDB(tx) {
    console.log("setupDB()");
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,code,updated, latitude, longitude)");
}

function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successInsert() {
    console.log("successInsert()");
}
```

And I try to display the rows in another page:

```
function showCode() {
    console.log("showCode()");
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(parseDB, errorCB);
}

function parseDB(tx) {
    console.log("parseDB()");
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], writeEntries, errorCB);
}

function writeEntries(tx, results) {
    console.log("writeEntries()");
    var len = results.rows.length;
    document.write("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        document.write("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).code + " Latitude =  " + results.rows.item(i).latitude+ " Longitude =  " + results.rows.item(i).longitude );
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).code + " Latitude =  " + results.rows.item(i).latitude+ " Longitude =  " + results.rows.item(i).longitude);
    }
}
```

In the log, I can see the row created. But in the html page not (But it is another issue: JQuery issue). But when I try to add another row, the first row does not exist any more.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like setupDB is getting called every time you call launchDB and dropping the table if it exists.

There could also be some separate issues with the file access, but that drop table would be the first thing to fix.

Comment: Thank you! I tested it on another phone Device and it works when I delete the Drop statement :)